# Proof that the multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Is my proof for the question in the title correct?

Note that $\mathbb{R} - \{0\} \subset \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$, since every real number is a complex number. Therefore, since any $\phi: \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \to \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ would map from a set to another set of bigger cardinality, no such $\phi$ could be  surjective. Thus, no isomorphism exists between the multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$.

Comment: The two sets in question have the same cardinality, so there is a surjective map from one to the other. You have to use a different argument. Namely, you have to find something which is true of one of the groups, but not the other.

Comment: The argument about cardinality doesn't work because both groups are equicardinal.  Is there a cyclic subgroup of order $3$ in $\mathbb{R}^\times$?  How about $\mathbb{C}^\times$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lemma: If $X\cong Y$ via $f:X\to Y$, then $x$ and $f(x)$ have the same order.

Hint: What's the order of $i$? Does $\mathbb{R}-0$ have an element with this order?

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is an isomorphism between $(C-0,\times)$ and $(R-0,\times)$, $f(i)^2=-1$ impossible

Comment: You need to say more about why an isomorphism would send $-1$ to $-1$. (The answer is that in both groups $-1$ is the unique element of order exactly $2$.)

Comment: Nobody said that $f(-1)$ has to be $-1$, this is not the argument used here.

Comment: Okay, then maybe the argument is that $f(i)$ must be an element of order $4$, but if so then you should say that.

Comment: I continue to have no idea why you feel the need to be so rude to me. You claim to demonstrate a contradiction but don't say what that contradiction is. There are a few ways to get a contradiction from here but you should spell out which one you intend. I think I'm making a reasonable request for a clarification here and I don't know why you insist on responding with insults.

Comment: You have that $f(i)^2 = f(i^2) = f(-1)$, but you haven't provided an argument for why $f(-1) = -1$ (and in fact you claim that you don't use this fact). If you don't think your last comment was rude then why did you delete it?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, $$t(R^*,\cdot)=\{+1,-1\}\neq t(C^*,\cdot)=\{\exp(2ki\pi/n)|k,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ $t(G)$ means the torsion subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed $p \not= 2$ prime, take all the complex $p$-th  roots of $1$. It is a subgroup of order $p$, and every element has thus order $p$ (exept 1). On the contrary there no elements of order $p$ in the real numbers, and no subgroup of order $p$.